# Send notification mail to all user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to send a notification mail when an article is published on my Rails app

**Mailer class**

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def notification_mail(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: '**TEST**')
 end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
@idee = Idee.new(idee_params)
users = User.all
respond_to do |format|
  if @idee.save
    users.each do |user|
      AdminMailer.notification_mail(user).deliver_now
    end
    format.html { redirect_to @idee, notice: 'Votre idée a bien été publiée.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @idee }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @idee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

The problem is that it send an email just to one user and I don't know why. Is there a way to resolve this and send an email to all user ?

Comment: instead of local variable make it as instance variable and then try

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may try this

Idee.rb

```
after_create :send_email_to_users

def send_email_to_users
  User.all.each do |user|
    AdminMailer.notification_mail(user).deliver_now    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to an instance variable:

```
def create
  @idee = Idee.new(idee_params)
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @idee.save
      @users.each do |user|
        AdminMailer.notification_mail(user).deliver_now
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @idee, notice: 'Votre idée a bien été publiée.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @idee }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @idee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```